# Disabling SSL for a Heroku App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, heroku

I recently changed the domain for a Rails app I have running on Heroku. I redirected the original to the new one, and for the last couple of months have been running SSL on both. I tried to remove SSL from the original domain since all it does is redirect.

I did everything I thought I should:

- Turned off SSL in the app with `config.force_ssl = false` in production.rb
- Changed DNS ALIAS and CNAME to point to "myapp.herokuapp.com"
- Removed the SSL endpoint and certs

If I go to myapp.herokuapp.com, everything is fine, but if I go to myapp.com, or www.myapp.com it automatically tries to take me to the secure version of the site, https://myapp.com, and I get the standard security error warning from my browser.

Am I missing something? Is it a caching issue? Does it just take time for the DNS change to kick in? I've tried on a few machines/browsers, and the issue is consistent across all of them.

Worst case, I can definitely add the SSL Endpoint back on, but it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`config.force_ssl = true` enables [`Strict Transport Security`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) header(`HSTS`) with `max-age` of one year. See this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5123). Such header forces browsers that support it to contact the server over HTTPS for one year. This is to prevent attacks in which man in a middle downgrades HTTPS connection to HTTP.

Moving out of HTTPS for production sites that were served with `HSTS` is not very easy. You should keep your site served over HTTPS and return `HSTS` header with `max-age=0` to reset the one year setting. The problem is to decide for how long you need to keep HTTPS. To be absolutely sure that all clients are switched, you should do it for one year. You may decide to do it for a shorter period, but at the risk of breaking the site for clients that are visiting infrequently.

Comment: FYI, I found the following also usefull to get my browser to forget to use ssl after I had changed the configuration: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1027355. This of course only works for your own browser (but in my case I haven't shared the url with anyone yet). So if you already had visitors to your website, this wouldn't help them (unless they do the same on their computer).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what Jan said, here is what I did to do the trick.

In application_controller.rb :

```
before_filter :expire_hsts

[...]
private
  def expire_hsts
    response.headers["Strict-Transport-Security"] = 'max-age=0'
  end
```

In production.rb

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

**Clear the cache** of your web browser and that's it !

Comment: not work for me. "We're sorry, but something went wrong." shown on my page.