# How to remove an SSL redirect on Heroku and Godaddy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, https

I have a Heroku app that uses a Godaddy managed domain name. Last year I set up an SSL certificate on the app and redirected to the https:// using the CNAME section of the Godaddy domain panel. All worked perfectly.

This year the SSL certificate has come up for renewal, and as I'm no longer actively using the app I don't want to pay for the SSL cert or for the Heroku SSL functions. I do still want the app to work, but as it stands Google Chrome is protecting me from visiting the site as the SSL cert is out of date/invalid.

I've switched off the SSL features on Heroku and now want to point the CNAME back to a non-https address in my Godaddy control panel, but when I run Heroku domain:add www.mysite.com it still gives me the following:

```
Configure your app's DNS provider to point to the DNS Target kyoto-9249.herokussl.com
```

This is still pointing to the https:// address, and is throwing the same error. All the documentation on this (unsurprisingly) is about how to add SSL certs to the app, nothing tells me how to remove it. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how I can get rid of this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `heroku certs:remove` you should then see "Removing SSL Endpoint..." - it should then present you with the non-SSL endpoint again and be able to add your custom domain.

This won't stop the heroku billing for SSL module, however, so you would have to remove that too.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that now, and both *.myapp.com and www.myapp.com are now pointing at the .herokuapp.com endpoint in my Terminal. However when I go to visit the www.myapp.com site it still tries to take me to https://www.myapp.com and presents the security warning. Does it take Heroku time to propagate these changes or is it instant?

Comment: It will probably be down to your DNS - each DNS entry has a TTL and so it might take time. In my experience Heroku changes are practically instant. If you do `dig www.myapp.com in terminal` (on a *nix based machine) you'll see where it's pointing and can keep checking to see when it changes.

Comment: Thanks - I think I'm experiencing the issue laid out [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain) where the forwarding is causing the https:// error - I've disabled forwarding and will see if that works

Comment: I needed to follow the answers in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776530/disabling-ssl-for-a-heroku-app) thread too - now it works. Thanks for your help.